# How to get swf's url on swc library

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, flash, swc

I'am a beginner of ActionScript3

I wanna get swf's url.

but I develop swc lib.
swf(Main) develop other developer.

I have to get from Main loaderinfo, I / F is already fixed.

Do you have a good idea?

```
public function doSomething( arg1:String,arg2:String ):String
{
    /* some thing */

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Pleas explain in details

Comment: loaderInfo.loaderURL use on not MainObject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the other developer to pass in the Main class or the Stage (in fact any DisplayObject) and return the loaderInfo.loaderURL from that. Something like:

```
public function getSWFURL( dObj:Sprite ):String
{
    return dObj.root.loaderInfo.loaderURL;
}
```

the `.root` will return the root `DisplayObject`, so any `DisplayObject` that's attached to the stage will return this.

Comment: Thank you so much . but Do I have to edit my function?
    public function doSomething( arg1:String,arg2:String, dObj:Sprite):String
    {
        /* some thing */
    
        return result;
    }

Comment: provided the dObj that's passed in is on the Stage or attached to another DisplayObject that's on the stage, it should be fine. You should be able to call the code above